# R error with lapply

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have data as below.

```
visitor_id  timestamp   distance_value  guest_reviews   price   rating_value
--kkVxJWTRGDccUSZG9u2g  8/16/2016 14:03 7.441392    355 199     4.3
--kkVxJWTRGDccUSZG9u2g  8/16/2016 14:03 7.351424    359 110.67  4.4
--kkVxJWTRGDccUSZG9u2g  8/16/2016 14:03 17.556168   204 79.34   3.9
--kkVxJWTRGDccUSZG9u2g  8/16/2016 14:03 2.469943    429 159     4.2
-1IIpqtwRqeAV1P7yh0upw  8/10/2016 2:33  21.654525   142 58.79   4.1
-1IIpqtwRqeAV1P7yh0upw  8/10/2016 2:33  0.567264    436 83.29   4.4
-1IIpqtwRqeAV1P7yh0upw  8/10/2016 2:33  10.063784   195 56.95   4.2
```

trying to use the lapply on the last 4 column to normalize them with scale function

```
cols<-c("distance_value","min_avg_nightly_before_tax","rating_value","guest_reviews")
norm_cols<-c("norm_distance_value","norm_min_avg_nightly_before_tax","norm_rating_value","norm_guest_reviews")

myframe1[, (norm_cols):=lapply(.SD, scale), by= list(visitor_id, timestamp), .SDcols=cols]
```

However this is giving me the below error

```
Error in `[.data.table`(myframe1, , `:=`((norm_cols), lapply(.SD, scale)),  : 
  All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. If you are trying something like j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then use := by group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge afterwards.
```

Here is the partial output from a sample data output from dput(head(myframe2))

> "Zzy8RX7KSniWaNLyHwUXvQ", "zZYJITYrSHmYJv8MUDw6Cw",
>   "zzZ6OXcvROe88wD4JjTtnA",  "zzZBq1DsQe6PYM7AQNmbUQ",
>   "zzzi__t-SRW9OZOKBdDfwg", "ZZZTTaS6RD6bQ2KzdaiSVA" ), class =
>   "factor"), timestamp = structure(c(1471381408.339, 
>   1471381408.339, 1471381408.339, 1471381408.339, 1471381408.339, 
>   1471381408.339), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), distance_value = c(7.4413922836545, 
>   7.35142425353227, 17.5561677012408, 2.46994294033727, 24.8529546453572, 
>   21.8463254946658), rating_value = c(4.3, 4.4, 3.9, 4.2, 3.1, 
>   4.4), guest_reviews = c(355L, 359L, 204L, 429L, 305L, 633L), 
>       min_avg_nightly_before_tax = c(199, 110.67, 79.34, 159, 77.62, 
>       101.37)), .Names = c("visitor_id", "timestamp", "distance_value",  "rating_value", "guest_reviews", "min_avg_nightly_before_tax" ),
>   row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I suspect you need `myframe1[, (cols):=lapply(.SD, scale), by= list(visitor_id, timestamp), .SDcols=norm_cols]`

Comment: Partial output doesn't help much.  We can't load that into our R

Comment: @RichScriven sorry, the output didn't even fit my whole screen. can you advice how I can fit into a screen or post here

Comment: share a minimal subset of your data using the `dput` function